# discord.py - Не работает база данных

Tags: python, discord.py

Пишу бота для банка так скажем, и у меня выдает ошибку, полагаю что из-за неправильной переменной basecheckuser, но сам я не представляю что я неправильно написал.

Текст ошибки:

> File "main.py", line 55, in register
> if basecheckuser[1] == 0:
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

````
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def register(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send('Для начала укажите пользователя в формате t.register @user')
  else:
    basecheckuser = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE userid == ?'.format(name),(member.id,)).fetchone()
    if basecheckuser[1] == 0:
      member.send('Ваш 1 счет банка Tavave зарегистрирован.')
    else:
      ctx.send('Вы достигли максимального количества счетов.')```
````

Comment: Запрос не находит запись, поэтому `fetchone` возвращает `None` и вы получаете данную ошибку. Нет у вас записи с данным `userid`. Еще не знаю, что у вас за БД, но `==` - это нестандартный оператор. Сравнение нужно делать `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь что ваш запрос в базу точно тип инт возвращает, чтобы проверить, попробуйте

```py
print(basecheckuser[1].type)
```

Он должен напечатать вам тип. Если не инт, то разбирайтесь уже с тем что вы сохраняете в базу.